# React Absolute Import Paths

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am fairly new to React, using version 18.2.0.

I just can't seem to get "paths" in jsconfig.json to work.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@/models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@/public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@/src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["src/styles/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./"],
  "exclude":["node_modules","build"]
 }
```

My imports just don't work.

From src/App.js:

```
import '@/styles/App.scss';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
```

I'm also reading about other libraries that seem to do this? Is absolute paths a feature that's available in react? I'd rather not have to download and maintain a 3rd party library.

What's the standard approach?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this config in tsconfig.json for absolute import

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
       "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
       ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": false,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "baseUrl": "./src"
     },
     "include": ["src/index.tsx","src/custom.d.ts","src/react-app- env.d.ts"],
}
```

And your imports would be.

```
import 'styles/App.scss';
import Navbar from 'components/Navbar';
```

Comment: Did you intend to ask a question in your answer?  If so it belongs as comment, otherwise you should replace the interrogative statement with a declarative statement.

Comment: Thanks Behrouz, I am wanting to avoid using typescript though. So React doesn't use the "paths" section anymore, just the base url as the absolute path? Seems like a step backwards.